# Mysql (InnoDB) config settings for better performance?

Tags: mysql

Recently I updated my VPS from 1GB to 4GB memory. I'd hoped that the queries (MYSQL/InnoDB) were running faster with more memory, but unfortunately that's not the case. Does mysql automatically takes more memory when a server has more memory or do I have to change some settings in my.cnf? And if so, what changes should I make?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. You main focus in improve perfomance is analyze the query.  Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Yes, I'm also working on optimizing the queries off course. I want to optimize everything, the settings, the queries, indexes, etc.

Comment: What kind of mysql engine do you use for your tables? Give us more info about the DB :)

Comment: The engine is InnoDB.

Comment: You should probably better ask in [BDA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). However i would expect most improvement from increasing *innodb_buffer_pool_size*.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will not automatically take the benefit of more memory installed.

In your case (given that you are using `InnoDB`) you can do at least these to improve the performance of mysql:

- increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (default value for this option is **128MB**). This defines how much memory is dedicated to mysql innodb to cache its data tables and idexes. Which means if you can allocate more memory mysql will cache more of its data resulting in faster queries (because mysql will look in memory instead of doing I/O operations for data lookup).
  Of course you should allocate reasonable amount of memory (not the whole **4G** :)) may be **not more than 2G**. You should try and test it on the server for more accurate result. (read this for more info, before you change this option https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html)
- increase `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`. For you case may be 1 or 2 instances are more than enough. (you can read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances)

But before starting with editing of `my.ini` do your calculations for your case. Consider your mysql server load, slow queries etc. for more accurate setup of the options in `my.ini`